# How to avoid dropping of nodes on the tree using jstree v3.0.4?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, tree, jstree

I have JSON data which is displayed using jstree. I do not want them to be dropped on the tree, i.e., I do not want to reorder the nodes within the tree but must allow it to be dragged and dropped on an external droppable.
As i see, jstree v3.0.4 does not support "crrm" plugin. How do I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `"dnd"` plugin included in your `plugins` config option. Then use `core.check_callback` and prevent any drop operation:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
  plugins : ["dnd"],
  core : {
    check_callback : function (op) {
      if(op === "move_node" || op === "copy_node") {
        return false;
      }
      // you may not want to return true here - configure as needed
      return true;
    },
    ...
```

I am assuming you do not need help with the external droppable? If you do need help: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jstree/BYppISuCFRE/KKh7oHZzNkwJ

Best regards,
Ivan